# Python tensorly parafac returning ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, tensorly

I have a set of manufactured data (generated from an explicit mathematical function) stored in a 3-dimensional tensor called `A`.
When I try to run parafac, I receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ParafacPrintValues.py", line 145, in <module>
    A1, A2, A3 = parafac(A,2)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I am importing parafac like this:

```
from tensorly.decomposition import parafac
```

I installed (and just updated, again) the tensorly library with:

```
pip3 install -U tensorly
```

However, when I run the identical code in a Jupyter notebook, it works as expected.
It appears that there is a difference between what I have installed via Pip and what is in the IPython of the Jupyter notebook.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of TensorLy, [parafac](http://tensorly.org/stable/modules/generated/tensorly.decomposition.parafac.html#tensorly.decomposition.parafac) returns a CPTensor that acts as a tuple (weight, factors) : in addition to the factors of the decomposition, you also get a vector of weights. This is because the CP decomposition expresses the original tensor as a weighted sum of rank-1 tensors.

In other words, if you are using the latest version of TensorLy, your code should be either:

```
weights, factors = parafac(tensor, rank)
```

or, if you want to explicitly store each factor in a variable as in your example:

```
weights, (A1, A2, A3) = parafac(tensor, rank)
```

Comment: Excellent answer Jean.  This explains the difference in the behavior I was seeing between the two versions.  Thanks.